# Positioning a div at the bottom of the page issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

i am working on this [website](http://ap.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/) and as you can see i have this

`<div class="bt-op-item-builder-content">...</div>` (i setted a green border) at the bottom of every single page.

This works on Chrome, Safari, Microsoft Edge **but not on INTERNET EXPLORER 11.**

How can i move it at the bottom **also on Internet Explorer 11?**

**CSS:**

```
.bt-op-item-content .builder-custom-op_bt_6641.bt-op-item-builder .bt-op-item-builder-content {
padding: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
}
```

Thanks in advice

PS: Some screens

[Internet Explorer 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yrgpw.jpg)

Comment: please share your css code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update like this it will work

- `.btnav-container .bt-op-item .bt-op-item-builder`'s parent need to have `position: relative` so the absolute positioned element is relative to it
- `.btnav-container .bt-op-item .bt-op-item-builder` need an absolute position for the `bottom: 0px !important` to work
- `.btnav-container .bt-op-item .bt-op-item-builder` need `left: 0` or else it start of screen

Updated CSS rules

```
.btnav-container[data-fullscreen-scroll=yes] .bt-op-item .fp-tableCell .bt-op-item-content {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;          /*  added    */
}

.btnav-container .bt-op-item .bt-op-item-builder {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;            /*  changed  */
  left: 0;                       /*  added    */
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```